# Why doesn't my List<string> bind to a series of hidden fields when using Html.Hidden()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, forms, modelbinders, model-binding

I'm trying to use the default model binder in asp.net mvc to bind a list of hidden fields

```
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/string/one/here" />
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/another/string/here" />
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
```

To a `List<string>` like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Move(List<string> entity)
    {
        return View(entity);
    }
```

When I post the form, the view displays the contents of the list like this:

```
        <%foreach (string item in Model)
          {%>

          <%: Html.Hidden("entity", item)%>
          <!--binding not working correctly -->

        <%} %>
```

And the generated content is this:

```
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
```

I'm confuseled. I tried changing the initial hidden field to this:

```
<input id="entity__" name="entity[]" type="hidden" value="/string/one/here" />
<input id="entity__" name="entity[]" type="hidden" value="/another/string/here" />
<input id="entity__" name="entity[]" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
```

But when I tried posting that I got this error:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on this line of code in the view:

```
<%foreach (string item in Model)
```

I've been able to bind list of strings before... without using an index in the name. I don't understand why this isn't working correctly. Maybe a fresh set of eyes could help me out with this?

Thanks

### edit

In continuing to expirement. I ditched the HtmlHelper and hardcoded a hidden field inside the `foreach` loop like this:

```
<%foreach (string item in Model)
  {%>
      <input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="<%:item %>" />
<%} %>
```

This **worked**. I have no idea what the difference is between the Html helper's code and this so I put the two side by side and tried to match them up.

```
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="//Content/files/NewDirectory/Aesculuparviflora011cm.jpg" />
<input id="entity" name="entity" type="hidden" value="//Content/files/NewDirectory/Aesculuparviflora011cm.jpg" />
```

They are identical. But the binding works when I hardcode tags and it doesn't work when i use the html helper. What gives?????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using loops and non-strongly typed helpers in a strongly typed view? Things could be so simple with editor templates:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new[] 
        {
            "/string/one/here", "/another/string/here", "/last/string/here"    
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<string> items)
    {
        return View(items);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding view (`~/Views/Home/Index.aspx`):

```
<%@ Page 
    Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<string>>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

and the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/Index/EditorTemplates/string.ascx`):

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<string>" %>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(x => x) %>
```

Now you no longer need to worry about values not properly binding, writing loops in your views, ... you can finally concentrate on the real business logic of the application.

Comment: you're right that I should be using a `Html.HiddenFor()` but having a foreach loop seems more straightforward to me than creating another file as an editor template. Just my opinion. All I want is a list of hidden fields. If it was a complex object I would certainly use `editorFor`

Comment: @quakkels, sorry but I completely disagree that writing a `foreach` loop in a view is better and more straightforward than using an editor template :-)

Comment: I respect your opinion very much as you have helped me on Stackoverflow before. Usually I end up doing it your way. This might ending up being the same. And, 99% of the time I would agree with you - but when dealing with <em>just</em> a `List<string>` I think that fewer files = less complexity. But that's only an opinion. I think Scott Gu was once asked about why they didn't build DataGrids into MVC and he said something to the effect of 'We did. It's called foreach'... bu that could be hearsay as i don't have a reference to the quote.

Comment: @quakkels, I am sure that if Scott Gu ever said that it was back in the early days of ASP.NET MVC 1.0 when concepts like strongly typed helpers and editor templates didn't exist. But now it's 2011 and ASP.NET MVC 3 is out, so take profit from what it has to offer :-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<input id="entity" name="entity0" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" /> 
<input id="entity" name="entity1" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" /> 
<input id="entity" name="entity2" type="hidden" value="/last/string/here" />
```

Comment: According to Scott Hanselman (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) you should be able to bind simple data types like this to Lists without supllying and index number. (skip to the last paragraph.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually cannot recreate your problem:
This is my code, I tried fiddling with it and I cannot get it to malfunction.
perhaps check so that your view inherits the right type. Please post all of your code neccessary to make it malfunction.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        var strings = new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" };

        return View(strings);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<string> strings)
    {

        return View(strings);
    }
```

aspx page

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<string>>" %>
        <%using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>

        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

            <%:Html.Hidden("strings", item)%>   

        <% } %>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <% } %>
```

Comment: I'll wont be able to post that code for a bit. As soon as I have some time I'll try to get complete code up here that recreates my prblem.